# Find columns within a certain percentile of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

Having a multi-column dataframe, I'm interested in how to keep/get the part of the dataframe that fall between the 25th and 75th percentiles per each column ?
I need to remove the rows (which are just time steps) that have values outside the 25-75 percentile range

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
       '400.0': [13.909261, 13.758734, 13.513627, 13.095409, 13.628918, 12.782643, 13.278548, 13.160153, 12.155895, 12.152373, 12.147820, 13.023997, 15.010729, 13.006050, 13.002356],
       '401.0': [14.581624, 14.173803, 13.757856, 14.223524, 14.695623, 13.818065, 13.300235, 13.173674, 14.145402, 14.144456, 13.142969, 13.022471, 14.010802, 14.006181, 14.002641],
       '402.0': [15.253988, 15.588872, 15.002085, 15.351638, 14.762327, 14.853486, 15.321922, 14.187195, 15.134910, 15.136539, 15.138118, 15.020945, 15.010875, 15.006313, 15.002927],
       '403.0': [15.633908, 14.833914, 15.146499, 15.431543, 15.798185, 14.874350, 14.333470, 14.192128, 15.130119, 15.134795, 15.136049, 15.019307, 15.012037, 15.006674, 15.003002],
       })
```

I expect to see a lower number of rows, so I have to eliminate a range of measurements that act as outliers of the timeseries.

[image]

This is from the original data set, where the x-axis shows the rows. So I need somehow to remove this blob by setting a percentile criteria

At the end I'd take the most strict criteria to apply it for the entire dataframe

Comment: Do you mean to keep the rows that fall between the 25th and 75th percentile of a certain column? How do you define if an entire row falls between those percentiles?

Comment: I'll update the post, good question. I mean the percentiles per each column, exactly!

Comment: Within the 25th and 75th percentile of which column?  And if its all the columns do you mean depth as well (since it has a different kind of label to all the other columns) I suspect you might mean keep the value of that column WHERE the others are within the limits but if those limits apply to all the other columns the then what is supposed to happen?  Short version - what do you expect to see?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post: I expect to see a lower number of rows, so I have to eliminate a range of measurements that act as outliers of the timeseries. The depth column here is obsolete, the other ones should each fall within the 25-75 percentile, so I guess at the end I'd take the most strict criteria to apply it for the entire dataframe

Comment: I think the confusion stems from the fact that a row will have multiple values. Each of those values can separately be labeled as an outlier for its respective column. So, do you want to drop a row if `any` of the values are outside, or only if `all`. Or, perhaps set a threshold?

Comment: Yes, exactly, let's say I have 1000 rows and a certain part of a timeseries does some odd job and it reflects on the lower values for that set of rows. So I need to detect that. I'll attach a plot of the original (not shrinked) dataframe, so you can see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, but IIUC, you can create a mask, then apply it to your dataframe.

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.between(x.quantile(.25), x.quantile(.75))).all(1)]

       400.0      401.0      402.0      403.0
8  12.155895  14.145402  15.134910  15.130119
9  12.152373  14.144456  15.136539  15.134795
```

That will drop any row which contains any value in any column that falls outside your range.

If instead you want to only drop rows which contain *all* values that fall outside your range, you can use:

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.between(x.quantile(.25), x.quantile(.75))).any(1)]

        400.0      401.0      402.0      403.0
2   13.513627  13.757856  15.002085  15.146499
3   13.095409  14.223524  15.351638  15.431543
5   12.782643  13.818065  14.853486  14.874350
6   13.278548  13.300235  15.321922  14.333470
7   13.160153  13.173674  14.187195  14.192128
8   12.155895  14.145402  15.134910  15.130119
9   12.152373  14.144456  15.136539  15.134795
10  12.147820  13.142969  15.138118  15.136049
11  13.023997  13.022471  15.020945  15.019307
12   0.010729  14.010802  15.010875  15.012037
13   0.006050  14.006181  15.006313  15.006674
14   0.002356  14.002641  15.002927  15.003002
```

Rows are retained here if any of the values in any column falls within the percentile range in its respective column.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to be much faster to operate on the underlying `numpy` arrays here:

```
a = df1.values
q1 = np.quantile(a, q=0.25, axis=0)
q2 = np.quantile(a, q=0.75, axis=0)

mask = ((q1 < a) & (a < q2)).all(1)

df1[mask]
```

```
       400.0      401.0      402.0      403.0
8  12.155895  14.145402  15.134910  15.130119
9  12.152373  14.144456  15.136539  15.134795
```

Invert the mask (`df[~mask]`) if you want to *exclude* those rows